# Apache .htaccess - removing www, excluding sub-domain and 2nd level domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect any domain in a form of

```
****.**** (e.g. hello.com, hello.org, hello.ca, hello.net)
```

to

```
www.*****.*****
```

Using .htaccess - Above is easy.

I also need to EXCLUDE any subdomains. So if I have

```
test.hello.com
```

it should just go to

```
test.hello.com
```

Instead of

```
www.test.hello.com
```

I've achieved both of the conditions above with the following .htaccess file

```
# Exclude any subdomain:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
# redirect to www.:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But on top of this, I now need to redirect all second-level domains to www. So if you type in

```
hello.com.au
```

it should go to

```
www.hello.com.au
```

But if you type

```
test.hello.com.au
```

You should just go to

```
test.hello.com.au
```

Is this do-able?

Comment: Do you not have a main TLD domain? Why do want to do any?

Comment: My site allows users to direct their own domain name to my server.